# Tornado equivalent to Twisted's dataReceived?

Tags: python, sockets, twisted, tornado

Having used Twisted first, I might not be approaching the problem of bidirectional communication the right way with Tornado.

The Twisted way to receive data would be:

```
class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        # Figure out if this is a chunk of a previous message
        # or if it's a new message
```

I'm doing this with Tornado, which seems to work but is somewhat different:

```
class MyClient(object):
    @coroutine
    def main_loop(self):
        while True:
            message_header = yield Task(self.stream.read_bytes, 8)

            # Read/write from here
```

The documentation doesn't seem to suggest any "cleaner" approach (or any approach, for that matter), so am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to Twisted's `Protocol` in `IOStream` would be something like `stream.read_until_close(callback=self.connectionLost, streaming_callback=self.dataReceived)`.  But it's more idiomatic to do what you've done in your second example, and use the other read methods (`read_bytes`, `read_until`, etc) to read out what you need in separate chunks.  Note that `IOStream` is not currently very coroutine-friendly (due to the separate close callback), so it's probably best to write code that interfaces directly with `IOStream` with explicit callbacks.